# In android SetText only takes resId

Tags: android, xamarin

This is probably super simple but I am having problems with the settext in android development.

The following code:

```
TextView countDownTextView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.countdownTimer);

countDownTextView.SetText ("New text");
```

gives the errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Widget.TextView.SetText(int)' has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'
```

Now settext should be (string) but for some reason when I write it, it wants int resid. How do I change the Textview with just settext and a string?

I have tried using a

```
string value ="new text"
```

but that didnt work either.

Made a simpler version, but get the same problem

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace CountdownTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "CountdownTest", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
        };

        TextView textV = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CallText);

        textV.SetText ("diverse");
    }
}
}
```

And the  XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CallText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Xamarin:

```
TextView countDownTextView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.countdownTimer);

countDownTextView.Text = "value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code

```
String value = "New Text";
TextView countDownTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdownTimer);
countDownTextView.SetText (value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code to:

```
TextView countDownTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.countdownTimer );
countDownTextView.setText( "New text" );
```

Pay attention to the difference of my code to yours.

You're getting the wrong component and moreover is calling the methods in the wrong way. The letter "F" on findViewById should not be capitalized but tiny. The same applies to the Resource ID and inside the parentheses.

Comment: You have not written as code that I put here. Copy and paste the code there in your activity. Do not feel stupid.

Comment: If i write findViewById( R.id.countdownTimer ); it says it dosnt exist in the current context.

Comment: @user3729870 please edit your question with complete code of `activity` and `layout xml`

Comment: Sorry it took a while, but I made a simpler version. resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

just change like this and try

```
    TextView countDownTextView = (TextView)findViewById (R.Id.countdownTimer); 

    countDownTextView.SetText("New text");
```

Comment: I am feeling so stupid, but I tried writing this, like so

`TextView countdownTextView =(TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.countdownTimerText);

   countdownTextView.SetText ("New text");`

and it didnt work.

Comment: `(Resource.Id.countdownTimerText)` change this to `(R.Id.countdownTimerText)`

Comment: if I do it says it dosnt exist within the current context.

Comment: first check your R.java file that id is generate or not. after that write this one TextView countDownTextView = (TextView)findViewById (R.Id.countdownTimer); 
    countDownTextView.SetText("New text");

Comment: Added activity and xml

Comment: added activity and xml, simpler version resulting in the same error.

Comment: this is Android activity